# How limit the number of strategy entries (Consequence entries) to a specific condition?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

[image]

I am trying to restrict additional entries after intial one and till close condtion met (so after intial order fill and TP/SL reached, no other entries allowed till close condition occure, only then new entries are allowed again)
`Pyramiding` and `strategy.risk.max_intraday_filled_orders()` didn't solve my issue,
below is my code

````
strategy(title='EMA Cross', overlay=true)


tp_inp          = input(defval = 2.0, title='Take Profit %', type=input.float)/100
sl_inp          = input(defval = 2.0, title='Stop Loss %'  , type=input.float)/100
tp_inp_val = (1 + tp_inp)
sl_inp_val = (1 - sl_inp)
price = na(strategy.position_avg_price) ? close : strategy.position_avg_price
take_level = price * tp_inp_val
stop_level = price * sl_inp_val
useTake_level   = tp_inp         <= 1 and tp_inp != 0 ? take_level : na
useStop_level   = sl_inp         <= 1 and sl_inp != 0 ? stop_level : na
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? useTake_level : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2) // plot TP
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? useStop_level : na, color=color.red  , style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2) // plot SL

ema20  = ema(close, 20)
ema100 = ema(close, 100)

plot(ema20 , color = color.orange)
plot(ema100, color = color.blue  )

entry_allowed = true
if ema100 > ema20
    entry_allowed := true

if ema20>ema100
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when = ema20>ema100)
    entry_allowed := false
strategy.close("Buy", when = ema100 > ema20 )
strategy.exit("Exit Buy",  limit = useTake_level, stop=useStop_level) ```
````

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var entry_allowed = true

if (ema20>ema100) and entry_allowed
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    entry_allowed := false
    
if (ema100 > ema20) 
    strategy.close("Buy")
    entry_allowed := true

strategy.exit("Exit Buy",  limit = useTake_level, stop=useStop_level)
```